# TextWatcher - Backspace key on empty EditText

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am working on a remote control application and I have a fragment where I added an EditText field in order to capture the key events, because I need to send the information to the server which is running on my laptop, so the letters and the other characters could be seen on my laptop's screen.
When the EditText is empty I cannot use the backspace key, so I cannot delete the text that already exists on the screen. If I enter some text in the EditText field and if I'm pressing the backspace key, then the backspace key event is detected.

```
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    previousTextLength = s.length();


}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    char ch = newCharacter(s, previousText);
    if (ch == 0) {
        return;
    }
    MainActivity.sendMessageToServer("TYPE_CHARACTER");
    MainActivity.sendMessageToServer(Character.toString(ch));

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


}

private char newCharacter(CharSequence currentText, CharSequence previousText) {
    char ch = 0;
    currentTextLength = currentText.length();

    int difference = currentTextLength - previousTextLength;
    if (currentTextLength > previousTextLength) {
        if (1 == difference) {
            ch = currentText.charAt(previousTextLength);
        }
    } else if (currentTextLength < previousTextLength) {
        if (-1 == difference) {
            ch = '\b';
        } else {
            ch = ' ';
        }
    }
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to send each character to the server, or you can send the data after editing is done?

Comment: Also, what do you expect to do, on-press of backspace when the edit text is empty.

Comment: When the edit text is empty I would like to have the option of deleting the information that already exists on the screen. Right now if the edit text is empty and I press backspace nothing happens, but if I already typed a word in the edit text , the word is showing on my screen and when I press the backspace button I can delete it. The data is sent immediately, so is not necessary to type the word first and to hit a "Send" button. I can send each character to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onKeyListener` to detect if backspace is pressed as follows:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {  
            //Perform action for backspace
        }
        return false;       
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code,but now if the edit text is empty,when I press the backspace button the character that is sent to the server is the letter "c". So, instead of deleting the text that already exists on the screen, it adds the letter "c".

Comment: how did you derive character from backspace?

Comment: I have used '\b' .

Comment: Then it should be fine.Check the logic where you send the char to server. Job done by my code is just to deliver the backspace key press. It won't interfere with  your logic

Comment: I have tried Character.toString('\b') doesn't convert to 'c'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps as a work-around, you can force the first character of the EditText to be a [SPACE] or any prompt character you want..

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // You can replace ' ' and " " with any character you want. For example '>'
    if(s.length() == 0 || s.charAt(0) != ' ') {
        s.insert(0, " ");
    }
}
```

You might want to force the cursor to stay ahead of index 0...

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(editText.getSelectionStart() == 0) {
            editText.setSelection(1);
        }
    }
});
```

You might have to make appropriate changes to ignore the `s.insert(0, " ")` so as to not send it to the server.